# ATmega48 maximum AREF voltage

Tags: avr, atmega, atmel, maximum-ratings

The application that I want to use it for is 5V. However it could potentially have a future iteration where the reference voltage could be as high as 15V.

The plan is to run the ATmega48 at 3.3V.

I have been researching for what the maximum AREF reference voltage could be and it appears that it is 5.5VDC or so. Am I understanding this correctly? I would prefer to not have to use voltage dividers so that my voltage levels are exact and I do not lose precision in resistor tolerances. Am I over thinking this? The reason why I am worried about this is that I am looking at the input voltage and output voltage of mosfet transistors and knowing the Rdson value of the resistor then calculating the current flowing through the transistor.

If this is the case, then I will plan on just using voltage dividers on my pcb so that I can switch out resistor values to be able to use AREF values from 15V to 5V and not need a pcb change.

What AREF voltage input level should I design to?

Comment: Did you check the datasheet? If so, what chapter and could you link to it?

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. As expected I am planning on now using a voltage divider.

Comment: I am also not planning on using a shunt resistor due to the current that will be flowing at approximately 33A or so through each mosfet. I am also at 5VDC and with the high current I'm dropping too much voltage as it is through resistance in the wires.

Answer (score 4):

On page 323, the datasheet clearly states that Vref must not be more than AVcc, and that AVcc must be Vcc +/- 0.3 volts.

If your Vcc is 5 volts, the maximum Vref is also 5 volts.

It is very rare for any IC to accept input voltages outside its power supplies.

Answer (score 3):

The reference voltage limits for normal operation are described in the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf) table 29-15. It should be between AVcc and 1.0V.

[image]

Damage may occur if the reference input exceeds Vcc (which in turn must be within +/-0.3V of AVcc) +0.5V at any time, even briefly- that's in the 'Absolute Maximum' ratings, and it may not operate properly if the reference is too low.

So with Vcc = AVcc = 3.3V you should keep the Vref between 1.0 and 3.3V, and you'll probably get better results if Vref is towards the higher end of that range.

Generally you will need a buffer rather than just a voltage divider for Vref since it can draw significant current. You can add op-amp buffers for both the input and the reference and use two voltage dividers.

As others have said, measuring voltage drop across Rds(on) is not a very good idea. It is very variable from unit-to-unit and can increase ~50% as the MOSFET heats up. There are so-called [Sense-FETs](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/AND8093-D.PDF) that are essentially a small MOSFET in parallel with a larger MOSFET such that the current divides between the MOSFETs. That allows one to measure an analog of the current through the main FET without a sense resistor. In most cases, the resistor or some other current measuring device may be a better solution though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are relying on the \$R_{DS(on)}\$ parameter to be accurate, then your accuracy problem is not going to be in the divider resistors!

You should definitely keep AREF at or below your supply voltage. Any more than that and the ESD diode in the chip will forward conduct, then burn out.

You should definitely use a voltage divider on your sampled signal to reduce the voltage to be under your AREF voltage, which is below your VCC/AVCC voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the voltage measurement issue, there is a huge accuracy issue in using the MOSFET Rdson for measuring current. Rdson varies quite significantly (especially for Silicon FETs) with temperature and current. There is also good variation from individual part to part. If accuracy is important (and you seem worried about that since you talk about resistor tolerance issues), you will face issues due to the reasons mentioned. Consider looking into a series (shunt) resistor or a hall-effect device for current measurement.